# How do I run an ARM-based Docker container in Circle CI?

Tags: docker, arm, circleci

I have a docker image that contains all ARM binaries, except for a statically-linked x86 QEMU executable. It was specifically designed for doing ARM builds while on x86 hardware.

The base image is [show0k/miniconda-armv7](https://hub.docker.com/r/show0k/miniconda-armv7/). Since I don't use Conda, but do need Python, I then build atop it with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM show0k/miniconda-armv7
MAINTAINER savanni@cloudcity.io

RUN [ "cross-build-start" ]
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get -y install python3 python3-pip python3-venv ssh git iputils-ping
RUN [ "cross-build-end" ]
```

I can start this image perfectly on my machine and even run the build commands.

But, when I go to Circle, my container either gets hung up in a queue after "Spin up Environment", or I end frequently with this error message:

`Unexpected preparation error: Error response from daemon: Container d366de1282a32a79bca5265a8a97f573c8949f2838be231abcd234e5694d8d0b is not running` (where the container ID is different every time)

This is my Circle configuration file:

```
---
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: savannidgerinel/arm-python:latest

    working_directory: ~/repo

    steps:
      - run:
          name: test the image
          command: /bin/uname -a
```

Comment: I am having the same issue with the snapcraft/xenial-armhf image